# How to use cordova-plugin-splashscreen for iOS platform?

Tags: ios, cordova

In the [cordova-plugin-splashscreen](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen), there are only a little example.
I don't know how to use it for iOS platform.
Here are my questions:

1. any example?(both the config.xml and where did you place your images)
2. what does "resourcename" mean for in iOS platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Icons and Splash Screens](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/config_ref/images.html) Cordova docs for the example `config.xml` setup.
Note that `src` is relative to the project root folder (and not to the `www` folder):

`www
   css
   js
   index.html
   ...`

`res
   screen
     ios
       Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
       ...`

Ionic can also [automatically generate](http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/) splash screen and icons from a large image.

Comment: I mean how to use the plugin, not cordova. From cordova 6.0, the way you said to add splash screen can not be used any more.Thank you all the same.

Comment: It should work with cordova 6.0 as well. What issues are occurring? What do you mean by "the plugin, not cordova"? BTW the plugin docs will include the examples soon after [this PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/pull/90) is merged.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for me, the PR you provided is very useful.